# Spring Hadoop : Reading generic option

Tags: spring, hadoop

My project is integrated with Spring Hadoop. The jar file is invoked as 
hadoop jar  -DsomeKey=Somevalue

Now,how can i access this generic key (someKey) and value (Somevalue) from my Job.

I have set the below in my XML file.  But I still don't see the generic options passed to the jobs config.

Is there anything that I need to set explicitly?

Comment: Do you have some code/configuration that you tested so far?

Comment: Hi Andrei - Yes, I do have the code, but I cannot share it since its a production code.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using the Spring for Apache Hadoop tool tasklet.  If that's the case, you pass the args as arg elements.  Below is an example from using a Mahout job (my `hdp:configuration` has been left out because this is being run from Spring XD):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

    <hdp:tool-tasklet id="mahout-tasklet" jar="somepath/job/recommender/lib/mahout-core-0.9.jar"
                     tool-class="org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.similarity.item.ItemSimilarityJob">
        <hdp:arg value="-i/xd/hdfsImport"/>
        <hdp:arg value="-o/xd/hdfsImport/postsResults"/>
        <hdp:arg value="-sSIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE"/>
        <hdp:arg value="-booleanData=false"/>
    </hdp:tool-tasklet>

    <job id="job" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="step1">
            <tasklet ref="mahout-tasklet"/>
        </step>
    </job>
</beans>
```

Comment: Michael - Thanks for the response. But I am not using tasklet. I still need to pass the jar name and generic options as below.                                            Hadoop jar <Jar name> -D<somekey>=<somevalue>                                  All that I am trying is a way to read the generic options inside my code